# What does "Da kommt sein Schiff an eine kleine Insel" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can you help me at understanding this sentence?

> Da kommt sein Schiff an eine kleine Insel.

I know that *da* means *there*. I've looked it up in several dictionaries.
[Google Translate](https://translate.google.it/#auto/en/Da%20kommt%20sein%20Schiff%20an%20eine%20kleine%20insel), for instance, helped me a lot, suggesting the meaning of *sein* (i.e. *his*), but it also suggests that *da* means *as*.

I know that one meaning of [*sein*](http://it.bab.la/dizionario/tedesco-italiano/sein) is *to be*, but I could find that it is also used as a possessive pronoun.

So, I'm a little confused about *da* and *sein* in the sentence above. Could you help me clarify the intended meaning?

Comment: Mh, I just don't understand why somebody would use Google Translate if one wishes to learn a language.

Comment: @c.p. ... it is doing okay from Roman languages (Spanish, Portuguese to English). That is usually pretty readable and sometimes even well. But for German it is always epic fail, despite the languages being so close.

Comment: @Emanuel: however from german to english is acceptable.. you should see how it performs from german to italian :(

Comment: @Emanuel I didn't know. I've seen recently many questions based on nonsense obtained from automatic translators. Since I'm neither happy with the question nor taking an action can be justified, I [asked in the meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/678/how-to-deal-with-google-translate-says-but-it-doesnt-make-sense). Anyway all I said against it, is just prejudice: I don't think it would help to *learn*; maybe you get eventually a sentence right, but that was GT's effort ;)

Comment: @c.p.: I've used different websites (5 or 6), but I find useful also to use GT for learning. The reason is very simple. It has a contextual aware behavior. I understood sein to mean his in one second thanks to GT. I had to use 5 website to reach the same objective without it.

Comment: missing capitalization. `die Insel` is a 'Substantiv'

Comment: I also think that a downvote without any explanation should lead to the immediate ban from this website. Since it's showing the greatest lack of effort possible. But the community doesn't agree.. :-)

Comment: To keep voting private is a StackExchange-wide policy which also means that there will never be a need to explain a vote in a comment. If there were no comments we could only guess what issues led people to vote as they did here. From what I can guess two issues of your post may benefit from an edit 1.) show a research effort other than a machine's translation attempt 2.) avoid asking two questions in one. See [about] and [Meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences) for more.

Comment: @Takkat: I'm so sad that people judge a lack of effort while I put a good effort (the link, and also the cited session could show that), but I've tried to write of it. I hope it will help people to avoid hurried judging. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Well, I made some further changes. Although my changeset looks like I changed everything, it's actually not too much. You might take a look at it; if you disagree, feel free to rollback. – However, there's still missing some context! It won't really affect the answers, but I think it belongs into the question at any rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you speak Italian, so I'd say that in this case the best translation for "da" is "dunque" (dunque in english can be translated as "Then", it's often used to start sentences).

And "sein" is a possessive adjective. You can have a look [here](http://www.germanlanguageguide.com/german/grammar/possessive-adjective.asp) to go deeper.

Comment: 6 comments discussing Meta issues deleted. They were off topic to both, the question and the answer. Please discuss those issues in [meta].

Answer (score 4):

"Da" is a pretty generic pointer that can point to locations as well as to events.
"As" is not bad, but not the best either. Depending on the phrasing I'd use either "when" or "then"/"it was then, that"/"at that moment"... or nothing.

> Er wollte gerade in die Küche, da rief seine Freundin an.
>   He was about to go to the kitchen **when** his girlfriend called.
>
> Peter sagte "aoidufg". Da öffnete sich die Tür.
>   Peter said "aoidufg". It was then, that the door opened.

Answer (score 2):

The context would be helpful (is it a children song?) but here are my guesses:

- "Da" means "[and] then", i.e. it's temporal; cf "dann".
- "Sein" is certainly a possessive pronoun here.

In summary, I'd translate:

> [And] Then his ship arrived at a small island.

Or maybe:

> [And] Then his ship happened upon a small island.

Depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of that sentence is:

His ship is coming to a small island.

Most probably the sentence SHOULD be "ES kommt EIN Schiff an eine kleine Insel" - dbl check that :)

"Da" means 'there'.

Comment: _Most probably the sentence SHOULD.._ No, it certainly should not! It is perfect as written; it is in a 'story-telling' mode as in a fairy tale.